# Type Annotation For a Python Logger

Tags: python, logging, type-hinting, python-typing, type-annotation

I'm quite new to incorporating type hints in my Python code and often feel that I am on shaky ground while doing so. I have a function that creates and returns a custom logger and I'm wondering if I have *hinted* at the return type correctly.

```
import logging

def get_logger(param1: str, ...) -> logging.getLogger:
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    
    # define format
    # add handlers
   
    return logger
```

Is `logging.getLogger` the correct return type in this case? If not, what is the correct type?

Comment: Type hints are supposed to be types, which `getLogger` is not. Use `logging.Logger`.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thank you. If you could post this as answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type hints are supposed to use types. In the case of `getLogger()` it's `logging.Logger`:

```
import logging

def get_logger(param1: str, ...) -> logging.Logger:
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    
    # define format
    # add handlers
   
    return logger
```